# How to make localization module wise in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In lang folder of my particular module, I created 2 folders: one for english, and another one for my mother tongue.

> \en\scheme_error.php

```
<?php

return [
    'INTERNAL' =>  'INTERNAL IN ENGLSHI'
];
```

> \or\scheme_error.php

```
<?php

return [
    'INTERNAL' =>  'INTERNAL IN oriya'
];
```

But in routes, when I am doing dd like this `dd(__('scheme_error.INTERNAL'));`

I am getting it as plain text. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `INTERNAL IN ENGLSHI` => Did you just type it wrong in your question (instead of ENGLISH)?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get right text.

1. Set locale globally
   `app()->setLocale('en');`
2. Pass locale to trans function
   `trans('scheme_error.INTERNAL', [], 'en')`